# drupal how to have many links on primary menu on a sinle row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I face the following issue. I have a drupal theme installed on my site. After a while, i keep on adding links on the primary menu, and as a result, some of the menu links, get below the first links. How do you treat such cases?

If i make letters smaller, the site looks bad...

Answer (score 0):

There really is no easy answer to this. It's more of a design/philosophy question than anything, and those are always different answers for different people. A few things I would recommend though:

- whatever you do, [don't use a hamburger menu](http://jamesarcher.me/hamburger-menu). Or at least use it responsibly.
- figure out what you actually *really* need in that menu at the top level; many sites are too top heavy because the refuse to prioritize sections
- consider other modules that try reign in the menu craziness, like [tb_megamenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/)